# как получить расширение из Uri?

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь получить расширение из Uri скачаного файла на android 6
но получаю только пустой String или null

Как получить расширение из Uri ? пробовал на android 10 таких проблем нет.

Файл загружен с помощью Chrome и при передаче он показывает на своем экране имя и расширение и кнопку Открыть. Но видимо моему приложению эту информацию он не дает? Или я не правильно получаю?

```
private static String getFileMimeType(Context context, Uri uri){
    String urisceme = uri.getScheme();
    if(urisceme.equalsIgnoreCase(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)){
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String getType = context.getContentResolver().getType(uri);
        String ext = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(getType);

        boolean existExt = mime.hasMimeType(getType);
        if(existExt)
            return ext;
        else{
            String extF = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString());
            return extF;
        }
    }else{
        return MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(new File(uri.toString())).toString());
    }
}
```

[image: скриншот значений]

Comment: Судя по всему файл загружен из сети и загрузчик просто взял тип из ответа сервера. `application/octet-stream` - это просто байтовый поток, у него не может быть расширения, так как это вообще не файловый тип. Попробуйте добыть имя файла и из него уже по-старинке обрезать по точке. Имя можно получить так: https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info#RetrieveFileInfo

Comment: да, файл загружен с помощью Chrome и при передаче он показывает на своем экране имя и расширение и кнопку Открыть. Но видимо моему приложению эту информацию он не дает?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equals(uri.getScheme())) {
    try (Cursor returnCursor =
                         context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null)) {
        if (returnCursor != null && returnCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int mimeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE);
            return returnCursor.getString(mimeIndex);
        }
    } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: пробовал, но не проходит условие  moveToFirst()

Comment: cursor есть , но колво записей в нем 0

Comment: Как вы получаете этот uri? Похоже он вам просто не виден. Может бродкаста не хватает, android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, может пермишены...